# How to use this project (Interactive 3d mall map)https://github.com/codrops/Interactive3DMallMap on react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use this project(interactive 3D mall map) on my react project

I try to import javascript in many way but none of it work

i try to import js file directly through index.html file

```
<script src="..."></script>
```

And in my react file

```
import * as ... from "..."
```

Comment: try `import lib = require('...'}` also please post the errors that occur when you do `import * as ... from "..."`

Comment: @Matt - the source is straight non-module JavaScript. Script tags are used. But, since there is literally no documentation, the OP should submit an issue on GitHub.

Comment: is there anyway that i could use this source,no document is kinda rough since im just a newbie.